# PDO 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: mysql, pdo

I see many have had this same message for a number of different reasons but cannot see any solutions that seem to relate to my specific situation, which on the face of it a very simple one. Yes my password etc is md5 and should be changed but I do not believe that is the issue here.

I would appreciate someone pointing out why the first single line code works and the second does not. There is only one line that meets the criteria in the table in each case.

```
<?php

// Include database class
include 'DBClass.php';

// Instantiate database.
$db = new DBClass();

//***********************
// This works
//***********************

$em = 'admin@infin8integr8.com';
$sid = 39;
$db->query("select ufname,ulname from users where uemail = :em and sub_id = :sb");
$db->bind(':em', $em);
$db->bind(':sb', $sid);
$row = $db->single();

echo $row['ufname'].'  '.$row['ulname'].'<br>';

//***************************
// This returns the error 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in C:\wamp\www\pdo\DBClass.php on line 85
//*****************************

//Line 85 in DBClass is "return $this->stmt->execute();" in
    //public function execute(){
        //return $this->stmt->execute();
    //}

$userid = 'f534983b255eb2820bf3ba1438ddcf65';
$password = '0bfd2660362f242169d11e33f7affe0a';
$db->query = ("select ufname,ulname from users where username = :vuid and upwd = :vpwd");
$db->bind(':vuid', $userid);
$db->bind(':vpwd', $password);
$row = $db->single();

echo $row['ufname'].' * '.$row['ulname'].'<br>';

?>

The relevant class code is:-
<?php
class DBClass{

    private $host      = 'localhost';
    private $user      = '<user>';
    private $pass      = '<password>';
    private $dbname    = 'infinint_infin8';

    private $dbh;
    private $error;
    private $stmt;

    public function __construct(){
        // Set DSN
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
       // Set options
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8");
        // Create a new PDO instanace
        try{
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        }
        // Catch any errors
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function query($query){
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }   

    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function execute(){
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }


    public function resultset(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function single(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }   
}
?>
```

Comment: `$db->bind` should be `$db->bindParam`

Comment: $db->bind is a method in my DBClass (included in above code) that uses bindValue. The issue is that it works perfectly with one set of bound parameters but not the other and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Resolved - $db->query = ("select ufname,ulname from users where username = :vuid and upwd = :vpwd"); should be $db->query("select ufname,ulname from users where username = :vuid and upwd = :vpwd");